# Any browser for LibreElec/Kodi von RPi 1 B?

Tags: kodi, openelec, web-browsers

I was just wondering why there is no browser for Kodi Krypton on LibreElec on my Raspberry Pi (Model B Rev 2)?

**Many forums state that there is no Chromium or Firefox browser for ARM processors like the Raspi has. But why is there a Firefox-ESR browser in vanilla Debian?**

Debian also runs on the Raspi so why couldn't it work on LibreElec/Kodi v17.6?

Or do you guys know any browser for Libre/OpenELEC?

--

Background: I want to open the website http://jukebox.today/test and play music and view it on my TV.*

Comment: Edited it. Well, I don't want to use OSMC, because I don't like the interface (and support). And considering Raspbian with Kodi installed, I think it could be too much for my RPi 1 B ...?

Comment: well, if you want to run a browser, I don't think libreelec is for you

Comment: to be perfectly honest, if that non-existent site (I can't connect to it) plays videos in the browser, you won't have much of a good time with ANY pi - because pi + videos in browsers = sucky experience - for music only though, it'd be fine

Comment: Link fixed. no videos, only music streaming.

Comment: my advice is to load rasbian, install kodi, and give it a go ... you wont be running kodi and a browser at the same time anyway :p and raspbian can run kodi (the dozens of OSMC users can tell you that)